# How to get div id using mouseover to show popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-5

Suppose, I've many div. Now I want to show separate popover, div wise. I used mouseover. It's working well. But 1st time not working. When I moved the mouse 2nd time, it's working.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".popper").one('mousemove', function() {
    var messageId = this.id;
    console.log(messageId);
    $("#" + messageId).popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function() {
        return $('.popper-content-' + messageId).html();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 120px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="1" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="2" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="3" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="4" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>


<div class="popper-content-1 d-none">My <b class="red">first</b> button popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-2 d-none">My <b class="red">second</b> button popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-3 d-none">My <b class="red">third</b> popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-4 d-none">My <b class="red">fourth</b> popover content goes here.</div>
```

How do I show the popover first time also?

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off topic: `var messageId = this.id; $("#" + messageId)` *will be* the same as just `$(this)` (assuming you don't have duplicate IDs)

Comment: @Dev I see you have revoked the approval. Have you had any problems? Feel free to write a comment.

Comment: @BOZ Sorry. It was my mistake. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to hover first and show the `popover()` manually since you're building it later.

```js
.popover('show');
```

### Example snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".popper").one('mousemove', function() {
    var messageId = this.id;
    console.log(messageId);
    $("#" + messageId).popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function() {
        return $('.popper-content-' + messageId).html();
      }
    }).popover('show');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 120px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="1" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="2" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="3" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>
<a class="popper btn btn-outline-warning" id="4" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-toggle="popover">Hover me</a>


<div class="popper-content-1 d-none">My <b class="red">first</b> button popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-2 d-none">My <b class="red">second</b> button popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-3 d-none">My <b class="red">third</b> popover content goes here.</div>
<div class="popper-content-4 d-none">My <b class="red">fourth</b> popover content goes here.</div>
```